# Magento 1.9.2 Online Customers not giving correct url

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I just installed Magento 1.9.2 with sample data. I haven't done any tweaks yet. 
But when navigating to `Customer > Online Customer` in the backend, the `Last Url` visited column shows the **base url** of the site, no matter where the Customer(whether logged in or not) is browsing.
I tried changing `System > Customers > Customer Configuration > Online Customer Options > Online Minutes Interval` to a smaller value. Also I tried changing `System > Advanced > System > Log > Enable Log` to **Yes**, but the `Last Url` column does not show the correct value.

[Screenshot of online customers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZdvS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the default functionality of magento. Online customer grid will only show last visited url by perticular customer. This thing is based on IP Address and customer login ID(if logged in).

```
System > Advanced > System > Log > Enable Logging
```

**Logging** Feature is used to log the errors at runtime. You can find those logs at var/log directory. Dont be confused between "Online customer" and "Logging" feature.

Hope you understood!!

Comment: So, if the customer is not logged in, the last visited url does not work. Is this correct?

Comment: It will work. If customer is logged in from frontend then Admin can see customer's recently visited URL. Magento does not store all visited url. it will just show single url in grid.

Comment: This isn't working. The screenshot above is when I was browsing logged in as a Customer, and at a Product Detail page. I know this is a lot to ask, but can you please check this? I even installed a fresh copy of Magento, but it's not working there as well. I just want to know that this actually works and I am not doing something wrong.